# How to store facebook user's information(except password) in MySql DB, when a user logs into my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook code integration. I've gone through a bit of documentation and many questions on Stackoverflow. I just want to access the details of a person who is signing into my website with facebook login credential with his permissions. at present I was trying with following :

```
<?php
   $app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
   $app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
   $my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';
```

I've got $app_id and $app_secret by going into my facebook account. But I am unable to understand the meaning of $my_url. Is it the one running on my server? I am trying all these things on my localhost as I do not have my website running on the remote server. In case  it is required to have the website running on the remote server, can you please let me know the correct format of $my_url or if i've to set it somewhere in my facebook app while creating it. Perhaps, its a very basic question, but I will be unable to proceed without help. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$my_url is the postback URL.  It's where Facebook will post its response when you're asking for oauth credentials.  If you're using localhost you can provide that as the URI for facebook.  You can even provide the port.

E.g. for a rails app `http://localhost:3000` is acceptable.  Since facebook is posting back to that uri via your web browser, it will obey any rules you place in your hosts file as well, so you could use the production uri locally.

if you have www.myapp.com, but then add it to your hosts file as

127.0.0.1 www.myapp.com

it should also work.

Comment: Thanks Chris for a quick response. I'll just check it and come back to you.

Comment: Following is the error I am getting when I set the URL suggested by you. What can be the reason behind this error. lease help me.  API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: @ShashiRoy You also have to set the URL you type here in the **Application Settings** part in **Website with Facebook Login** and they both need to match

Comment: Hi Anvesh. Thanks for the response. I did it by applying the facebook link itself, including my apps namespace at the end of the URL. Its working now. Thanks again for your precious time.